# How to import some fields to Azure index which are not present in all document of CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I have 10 fields in cosmos DB for each document but not all fields are present in all documents. Now I want to create azure search index of 10 fields from cosmos DB but the indexer is only detecting fields which are present in all documents say 8 fields.

How to include the remaining 2 fields in azure search index so that it remains consistent? I want to put null for those 2 fields in the search index.

Comment: Just for check could you define all 10 fields in Query (*Set the data source* -> *Import Data* -> 'Query*)?

Comment: [Azure Search has an implicit dependency on Cosmos DB indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-troubleshooting#cosmos-db), so could you check that CosmosDB index not ignore these fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional fields(not detected by indexer) manually using `Add field` button on `{index-name}->Fields` tab